# Xamarin Form: GeoLocator Issue

Tags: xamarin, geolocation, mvvmcross

I have one issue is geo Locator that I have declared Time as 10 sec. then also in
 Android: it updates after 10 or more than 10 sec., In IOS: it updates in every sec.
This is my Code:

```
     public async void CurrentLocation()
    {

        try
        {
            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 0, true, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
            {
                ActivityType = Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
                AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
                //DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                ListenForSignificantChanges = false,
                PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

            });
            count++;
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += changedPosition;
        }
```

Please give me some solution. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the code https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/blob/master/src/Geolocator.Plugin/Apple/GeolocatorImplementation.apple.cs#L369 the `minimumTime` is not implemented in iOS (at least not yet).

In background it should work if you set `DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)` as the [docs](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/BackgroundUpdates.html) states:

> Summary: If deferring location updates, the minimum time that should elapse before updates are delivered (>= iOS 6). Set to null for indefinite wait. Default:  5 minutes
>
> Value: The time between updates

So in order to workaround your situation in foreground you could skip the locations that you don't want in your `PositionChanged` handler:

```
Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position lastPosition = null;
var timePeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

private void ChangedPosition(object sender, Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.PositionEventArgs e)
{
    var lapsed = e.Position.Timestamp - lastPosition.Timestamp;
    lastPosition = e.Position;

    if (lapsed < timePeriod)
        return;

    // your logic
}
```

this is what it basically does in the [Android implementation](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/blob/master/src/Geolocator.Plugin/Android/GeolocationContinuousListener.android.cs#L50) to accomplish it.

HIH